# XML reading in java returns illegal character in base64 decoding

Tags: xml, dom, base64, jms, decode

When I am reading input from JMS Topic it is successful in creating document and reading tags from it. Same content when I read from File, its throwing illegal character exception.

```
byte[] decoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encoded);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using,

```
encodedData.getMimeDecoder()
```

It will neglect invalid character like new line characters and process the input.

Comment: This helped. Thanks!